# Disable payment method based on time range in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, disable, payment-method

I want to disable the payment method, cash on delivery (COD) between *11pm* (current day) to *8am* (next day), in my WooCommerce store.

Based on some research, this is my code attempt:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateways_based_on_hour', 1 );
function payment_gateways_based_on_hour( $gateways ) {
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Lima');

   if ( isset( $gateways['cod'] ) && date('H') >= 23 && date('H') <= 8 ) {
        unset( $gateways['cod'] );
    }
    return $gateways;
}
```

Disabling the payment method works, but the time range is applied incorrectly, because the time span is pm/am (current day/next day) and not am/pm (same day, which does work)

Any advice on applying it to pm/am (current day/next day)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `woocommerce_available_payment_gateways` is a first step in the right direction. However, because you have an overlap of one night, a somewhat more extensive approach is needed.

I have added an array in my answer in which multiple payment methods can be added. However, this can also be limited to 1 specific.

To avoid problems (error) in WooCommerce backend, use `if ( is_admin() ) return $payment_gateways;`.

So you get:

```php
function the_time_range() {
    // Set the correct time zone (http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)
    date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Brussels' );

    // Settings
    $start_time = '11:00 pm'; 
    $end_time = '08:00 am'; 

    $date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'H:i a', date( 'h:i a' ) )->getTimestamp(); 
    $date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'H:i a', $start_time )->getTimestamp();
    $date3 = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'H:i a', $end_time )->getTimestamp();

    if ( $date3 < $date2 ) { 
        $date3 += 24 * 3600;

        if ( $date1 < $date2 ) { 
            $date1 += 24 * 3600; 
        } 

    }
    
    if ( $date1 > $date2 && $date1 < $date3 ) { 
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function filter_woocommerce_available_payment_gateways( $payment_gateways ) {
    // Not on admin
    if ( is_admin() ) return $payment_gateways;

    // Only on custom hour range (call function)
    if ( the_time_range() ) {
        // Add the payment methods you want to disable, several can be entered, separated by a comma
        $disable_payment_gateways = array( 'cod', 'bacs' );

        // Loop through
        foreach ( $disable_payment_gateways as $disable_payment_gateway ) {
            // When the payment method actually exists 
            if ( isset( $payment_gateways[$disable_payment_gateway] ) ) {
                // Unset
                unset( $payment_gateways[$disable_payment_gateway] );
            }
        } 
    }
    
    return $payment_gateways;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'filter_woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 10, 1 );
```